# Maven plugin prevents run of another one

Tags: maven

I am using two maven plugins within my build, one of them prepares files for the other one. Specifically, I am using maven-assembly-plugin to build jar file and then jdeb to create debian package. My problem is that once the second one (jdeb) is enabled, the first (maven-assembly-plugin) is never run.

My `pom.xml` is here: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/fa956d56b15bc2849d60

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried to use profiles as well: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/dd43a7e7df87c406b823

But it does not work as expected neither when invoked: `mvn package -Passembly,debian`. Will I always have to write the `-P` parameter? Is there a way to define "default profiles" to be run? I would like to call just `mvn package` to run both profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly plugin is not configured with an `execution`.  Add an execution to the assembly plugin, similar to the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>jarlib.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <outputDirectory>assembly</outputDirectory>
        <workDirectory>target/assembly/work</workDirectory>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <finalName>...</finalName>
        <attach>false</attach>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>...</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>do-assembly</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also, if you want to execute the assembly plugin before jdeb, ensure the assembly plugin is defined in the POM before jdeb.  [As of Maven 3.0.3](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2258), plugins defined to execute in the same phase will use the POM's order (before this order was arbitrary).

There is no need to use profiles unless you want to be able to disable execution of the plugins in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making profiles.  Since they're probably both using the package phase, only one is going to get invoked.  Using a profile you can separate them.